# Tensor.graph is meaningless when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
a = tf.compat.v1.constant(5.0)
b = tf.compat.v1.constant(6.0)

sum1 = a + b
g = tf.compat.v1.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    # Define operations and tensors in `g`.
    hello = tf.compat.v1.constant('hello')
    assert hello.graph is g

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g)

print(sess.run(sum1))
```

tensorflow-gpu2.0
i don't know why. i am a beginner of tensorflow

Comment: Can you give more details on what problems you are facing? It is quite ambiguous

Comment: Please go through some tutorials (like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)) to get yourself familiarized with TensorFlow. In version 2.x, [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is enabled by default so, as the error points out, you cannot use graphs and sessions. You could disable eager execution and go back to the 1.x way of doing things, but if you are getting starting with TensorFlow you would probably do well to learn 2.x and work with it.

Comment: import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf and
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 
try this and check once.

Answer (score 5):

After import tensorflow need disable eager execution, like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what you want to do! But I made some guesses and this is what I came up with as a result.

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.compat.v1.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    a = tf.compat.v1.constant(5.0)
    b = tf.compat.v1.constant(6.0)
    sum1 = tf.add(a, b) # instead of sum1 = a + b
    
    hello = tf.compat.v1.constant('hello')
    assert hello.graph is g

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g)

print(sess.run(sum1))
```

I believe it works with Tensorflow 2.x, If you still get eager exception then you should just add:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Before

```
assert hello.graph is g
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried tensorflow version 1.14.0

Do the following

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14..0
```

Try the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.compat.v1.constant(5.0)
b = tf.compat.v1.constant(6.0)

sum1 = a + b
g = tf.compat.v1.Graph()
with g.as_default():
# Define operations and tensors in `g`.
    hello = tf.compat.v1.constant('hello')
    assert hello.graph is g
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
#sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g)
print(sess.run(sum1))
```