# My TensorBoard callback conflicts with “tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster” function in Keras

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

"I did not use the TensorBoard callback at first. Later, I added the TensorBoard callback to the training function as shown in this image:
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtTWj.png)
.However, I encountered this error message
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erHSs.png)
Following suggestions from other posts online like this one [blog1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815710/tensor-graph-is-meaningless-when-eager-execution-is-enabled)，I added

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

But then I got this error message:[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnUr3.png)，Based on this error, I tried to enable eager execution mode with tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() before tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster.But then I encountered this error: [error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEri9.png).

Tensorflow version: 2.12.0,colab,keras

It seems like there might be a conflict between TensorBoard and “tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster”.Can somebody help me? Thank you very much.